# Mac Terminal return to basic theme

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, zsh

I thought it was a good idea to mess around with my terminal and install a lot of things I didn't know on to it. I have come to my senses are need to restore it so it is clean like the day I got it. I have looked around and can not find anything on google.

Is there any commands I can run which will wipe it and start a fresh?

This is what I stupidly installed

https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

I have tried running

```
rm -rf ~/.yadr
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in ~/.profile for anything strange. Usually that contains at most a PATH definition. Or, look in ~/.bash_profile. Take a copy first and delete anything you don't like the look of!